# Determine number of negative and positive numbers in an array

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

I need to determine the number of negative and positive numbers in an array in assembler. It seems that the assembler doesn't recognizes them as negative numbers. How can I solve this problem? I define the array this way:

```
word_array db 3, -2, 11, -1, -2, -7, -5, -20
```

I have this function that counts the positive ones:

```
count_positives:
mov dx, word [word_array + 2*ecx - 2]
cmp edx, 0
JL skip
inc ebx
skip:
loopnz count_positives
```

Comment: You declared your word_array as bytes with `db` . Maybe you meant to use `dw` (for a 16-bit _WORD_). like: `word_array dw 3, -2, 11, -1, -2, -7, -5, -20` . As well since you are using the lower 16-bits  of the `edx` register by using `dx` then I recommend that you change to `cmp dx, 0` instead of `cmp edx, 0` If you don't compare the right part of the register your negative numbers may appear positive.

Comment: Actually, use `test dx, dx`, or skip the load altogether and use `cmp word [word_array + 2*ecx - 2], 0`.  And don't use the `loop` instruction, it's slow.  Use `dec ecx / jnz`

Comment: @PeterCordes : since I was just commenting, I was trying to suggest WHY that existing code may not yield correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Read the comments

```
proc:
  mov si, data ; si points to the data
  mov cx, [len] ; cx gets the length of the data
  shr cx,1 ; the length was in bytes, we want words
  mov bx, 0
  mov dx, cx

checkNext:
  mov ax, [si]
  text ax, ax ; alternatively: test ax, 8000h
  js isNegative
  inc bx ; counting positive numbers

isNegative:
  add si, 2 ; moving to next word
  loop checkNext ; decrease cx, jump if not 0

  sub dx, bx ; bx has the positive numbers, dx - the negative ones
  ret ; done

data dw -1,2,-3,4
len dw $-data
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `mov dx, cx` after getting the length into cx, because you use dx without initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading into the low 16 bits of DX, leaving the high bits (including the sign bit) holding whatever garbage was there before.  Use 16-bit operand-size for your compare.

---

Count either negative or non-negative, and subtract that from the total count to get the other.

If you need to count negative and positive, then you need two counters, and a `test` or `cmp` followed by two branches (so that zero doesn't go into either counter).

Adapted from Sten's answer, but with some improvements.  Note that `test value, -1` is equivalent to `cmp value, 0`.

```
section .rodata

word_array dw -1,2,-3,4
len  equ $-word_array     ; length in bytes.  assembler constant, so we can mov reg, imm8/imm32   rather than loading it as data.

section .text
;; clobbers ESI, ECX.  Returns in EAX, EDX
proc:
  mov   esi, word_array  ; esi points to the array.  In MASM, use OFFSET word_array
  mov   ecx, len/2 - 1      ; [esi + ecx*2] points to the last element
  xor   edx, edx           ; non_neg_count = 0

countloop:
    ; cmp   [esi + ecx*2], 0   ; This can't macro-fuse (memory and immediate operand).  Also can't micro-fuse on SnB, because of a 2-reg addressing mode
  movsx   eax, word [esi + ecx*2]  ; use a 2-reg addressing mode to save loop overhead, since this there's no ALU execution port component to this insn.  It doesn't need to micro-fuse to be one uop
  test    eax, eax        ; can macro-fuse with js
  js isNegative
  inc   edx               ; counting non-negative numbers
isNegative:
  dec   ecx               ; can macro-fuse with jge, but probably won't unless alignment stops it from being decoded in the same cycle as the earlier test/js
  jge countloop       ; jge, not jnz, because we want ecx from [0 : len-1], rather than [1 : len]

; after the loop, ecx=-1, edx=non_neg_count
; neg_count = array_count - non_neg_count
  mov   eax, len/2
  sub   eax, edx        ;   eax =  neg_count

  ret    ; return values in eax, edx
```

The loop is 4 uops on Intel.  (Or more likely 5 on Sandybridge before Haswell, if both test/branch pairs hit the decoders in the same cycle so only one macro-fuses.  HSW can do 2 macro-fusions in a single decode group).

A branch-less version with `sets bl / add edx, ebx` might work well.

You could maybe save slightly on code size by zeroing eax, then using `scasw` in a loop to compare `ax` with [esi], and increment esi by two, but it's not usually a good choice for performance.

---

#### If positive vs. non-negative matters:

```
section .rodata

word_array dw -1,2,0,-3,4
len  equ $-word_array     ; length in bytes.  assembler constant, so we can mov reg, imm8/imm32   rather than loading it as data.

section .text
;; clobbers ESI, EDI, EBP.  Returns in EAX, EDX
proc_pos_and_neg:
  mov   esi, word_array   ; esi points to the array.  In MASM, use OFFSET word_array
  xor   edx, edx           ; pos_count = 0
  xor   eax, eax           ; neg_count = 0

  lea   edi, [esi + len]  ; points one past the end of the array
  xor   ebx, ebx          ; clear upper portion, because setcc r32 isn't available, only setcc r8  :(

countloop:
  cmp    word [esi], 0
  setg   bl               ; 0 or 1, depending on  array[i] > 0
  lea    edx, [edx + ebx]  ; add without affecting flags
  setl   bl
  add    eax, ebx          ; can clobber flags now

  add    esi, 2            ; simple pointer-increment
  cmp    esi, edi
  jb  countloop            ; loop while our pointer is below the pointer to one-past-the-end

ret     ; neg_count in eax,  pos_count in edx
```

And the zero count is `n - eax - edx` if you want it, where `n` is the number of elements.

I used a different loop structure here just for variety.  The loop should be 7 uops.

Reading ebx after setcc writes bl avoids a partial-register merge penalty because we xor-zeroed EBX outside the loop.  (A context switch or interrupt that saves/restores EBX will remove that performance benefit, but for short loops it's probably still worth hoisting the xor-zeroing out of the loop.)