# How to compare addresses in x86

Tags: x86, compare, memory-address

Below is an x86 program to find maximum number from a list of numbers. I am trying to exit from the loop when the ending address is reached. (It is marked with `data_ends:` label in the source code).

```
# Program to find maximum number
# Program should end when an ending address is reached
.section .data
.globl data_items                   
data_items:
#These are the data items
.long 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,33,22,11,66
data_ends:
.section .text
.globl _start                        
_start:
movl $0, %edi                        
movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax       
movl %eax, %ebx                      
start_loop:
incl %edi
# Problem in below line
cmpl data_items(,%edi,4), data_ends
je loop_exit
movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
cmpl %ebx, %eax
jle start_loop
movl %eax, %ebx
jmp start_loop
loop_exit:
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

However as can be seen from the `as` output below, the line `cmpl data_items(,%edi,4), data_ends` has some issue.

```
user $ as maxNum.s -o maxNum.o
maxNum.s: Assembler messages:
maxNum.s:28: Error: too many memory references for `cmp'
user $
```

Looks like syntax for `cmpl` instruction is wrong. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmpl data_items(,%edi,4), data_ends`  has two memory operands.  `cmp` isn't like `lea`.  If you give it a memory operand, it loads from it.

`cmp  $(data_ends - data_items) / 4, %edi` should do the trick.  With your source code, that assembles to `cmp    $0xd,%edi`.  Note that you're *not* comparing addresses, you're comparing a loop counter (used as an index) against a loop count.

If you started with a pointer in a register, and incremented it by 4 each iteration, then it would make sense to compare addresses.  To do that, you can compare two registers, or a register and an immediate.  (A symbol address is a compile-time constant that can be used as an immediate operand.  Remember you want the address itself, not what's stored there.)

For an example of both kinds of loop structure (index with offset vs incrementing a pointer and comparing against an end), see the two code blocks in [my answer to another beginner question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688532/224132).

Also, you should put read only data in the `.rodata` section, not `.data`.  And you should indent your instructions more than your labels.  That helps a *lot* with readability.

Comment: It worked when I started with a pointer in a register, and incremented it by 4 each iteration, and compared it with `$data_ends`. This was actually what I wanted to do. i.e. compare adress. So marking this as correct answer. However, the trick you told, `cmp  $(data_ends - data_items) / 4, %edi` results in a `segmentation fault: core dumped`. I dont know why there is a segmentation fault. It looked like a comparision between an immediate value and a register value, and no memory access at all.

Comment: @sps: Both ways are comparing a register against an immediate.  In one case, the immediate is a pointer, in the other the immediate is the max loop counter value.  If the code in your question segfaults when you do `cmp $(data_ends - data_items) / 4, %edi`, then you have a bug somewhere else.  Use a debugger to see *where* the segfault happens, because you're right, there's no way that instruction itself can fault.  (You can disassemble to double-check that, like I did to make sure that syntax worked :P)